# Wrong month result using angularJS date filter

Tags: angularjs, date, filter

I have this angularJS view that I want to render a date with this format: MMM YYYY
My data is giving me the modified date as a string like "20210410072612"
I have:

```
{{item.default['Date modified'].substr(4,2) | date:'MMM'}} {{item.default['Date modified'].substr(0,4)}}
```

The results from this are: **Jan 2021**
The correct result should be **Apr 2021** since when I remove the date:'MMM' filter I got **04 2021** Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please, check out AngularJS filter date option setting.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to accomplish the desired results creating my own filter as a function and call it like this.

```
{{ getMonthName( item.default['Date modified'].substr(4,2) ) }} {{item.default['Date modified'].substr(0,4)}}
```

The issue was that I was passing a string with the zero for the month number and the result would always be Jan